Inverse of a vector function
Let $$\varphi:(-\pi, \pi)\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3, \quad \varphi(u,v)=(\cos(u),\sin(u),v)$$
Prove that  the map $\varphi$ is injective, $C^\infty$, and invertible with continuous inverse map on its image.
My attempt:
Injectivity: Let $(u_0,v_0),(u_1,v_1)\in (-\pi,\pi)\times \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(u_0,v_0)=\varphi(u_1,v_1)$. It follows that
$$(\cos(u_0)=\cos(u_1)) \wedge (\sin(u_0)=\sin(u_1)) \wedge (v_0=v_1)$$
The first two conditions hold iff $u_0=u_1$ and $v_0=v_1$. So, the map $\varphi$ is injective.
Differentiability: The map $\varphi$ is $C^\infty$ because its components are $C^\infty$.
Invertibility: If I consider the restriction $\varphi:(-\pi,\pi)\times \mathbb{R}\to Im(\varphi)$, the map $\varphi$ is invertible. Let $p=(x,y,z)\in Im(\varphi)$. Then, I have $$x=\cos(u), \\ y=\sin(u),\\  z=v$$ for some $(u,v)\in (-\pi,\pi)\times \mathbb{R}$.
Now, what I want to do is write an explicit expression of $(x,y,z)\to (u,v)$ studying the cases. This will allow me to establish if the dependence is unique and continuous.
Any suggestions? Is there a easier way to conclude?

It would be much simpler to parametrize $\mathbb{R}^3$ in cylindrical coordinates (radius $\rho$, angle $\theta$, height $z$). Then the image of $\varphi$ is a cylinder and we can denote it as:
$$
\tilde{\varphi}\;:\;(-\pi,\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\ni(u,v)\longmapsto(1,u,v)\in\mathbb{R}\times(-\pi,\pi)\times\mathbb{R}
$$
And this map is clearly an injective, $C^{\infty}$, and invertible with continuous inverse map on its image.
Note for purists: cylindrical parametrization is good, because $\varphi\left((-\pi,\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\right) \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}\times\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$ which is necessary because cylindrical coordinates are not well defined on $\{0\}\times\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$.
